# Does keyset/cursor pagination scale query performance better than offset pagination?

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I am seeing behavior where the query that powers my infinite scrolling list seems to be slowing down as the number of rows grow.

Naturally, I used offset pagination because the library I am using just has you tack on an `.offset(n).limit(m)`, and after a few minutes everything just functionally worked, and it seems to be the common approach for pagination.

I am aware of the problem with offset pagination where it can cause duplicate/missing items if the list is updated, but I am mostly concerned with performance here. I read that offset pagination doesn't really take advantage of indexes like keyset/cursor pagination does?

So considering it's an infinite scrolling list and I don't need page numbers, I am wondering if someone could confirm that refactoring to use keyset/cursor pagination would make it so the pagination doesn't grind things to a halt at more rows. Also, I am under the assumption that keyset pagination and cursor pagination are actually different things, and that keyset pagination would be better than cursor pagination for this scenario?

Comment: Yes, that will most assuredly perform better.

Comment: Make sure it does not mean you have a scalability problem if you keep the cursors open why the users scroll. It might require more open database connections. You might be better off reading larger chunks into a cache and page through it and then use the offset method to get a new chunk. This also helps to recover from broken connections and minimizes open session or transaction usage (and if the cache is shared reduces db load a lot)

Comment: @eckes We must be talking about something different. With keyset pagination you retrieve the results page by page from the database, and there is no need to keep cursors open. The difference to `OFFSET` is that you are faster.

Comment: Indeed, I have switched from offset pagination to keyset pagination and it is much faster and far better suited for my infinite scrolling list. Query times went from 5s to 500ms. 

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is was commenting on cursor pagination